# Editing sort order of a Live iOS GameCenter Leaderboard

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I setup a GameCenter leaderboard on my iOS app. Unfortunately, I set the sort order for scores from 'Low to High', rather than 'High to Low'.  Now player's best scores appear as their lowest scores rather than their highest scores.

The app is now live and so I cannot seem to edit the sort order.  Does anyone know a clever way round this?  I tried linking to a different leaderboard, but it seems in Unity you cant link to specific leaderboards.